# remove div when .close is clicked

Tags: jquery

Do you know how to delete the div that contains .close link When the .close link is clicked? I was trying with `$(this).closest('div').remove()` but its not working...

```
$(".close").hide();
$(".delete-link").bind("click", function () {
  $(".close").addClass("active");
  $(".close").show();
  $(".close").bind("click", function () {
    $(this).css("background","red");
    $("#content-message").show();
    $(".delete-div").bind("click", function () {
      var teste = $(this).closest('div').remove().html();
      alert(teste);
    });
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/000dqyLd/

Comment: Wouldn't you just use `parent` instead of `closest` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(".close").hide();
$(".delete-link").bind("click", function () {
  $(".close").addClass("active");
  $(".close").show();
  $(".close").bind("click", function () {
    var $this = this; // 'x'-> element which was clicked
    $(this).css("background","red");
    $("#content-message").show();
    $(".delete-div").bind("click", function () {
      $($this).closest('.content-link').remove(); // find the closest element to the element which triggered the click event with class 'content-link' and remove it.
      $("#content-message").hide(); // optional
      $(".close").hide(); // optional
    });
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/szcq649v/3/

Comment: Sure. Glad to help :). Here's an updated version : https://jsfiddle.net/szcq649v/4/

Answer (score 1):

> While you want to make an action from element not related with the
>   element you want to make that action with you should pass something
>   like index() or something with data attribute .. so check this code

```
$(".close").hide();
 $(".delete-link").on("click", function () {
    $(".close").addClass("active").show();
  });
  $(".close").on("click", function () {
    var getIndex = $(this).closest('.content-link').index();
    $(this).css("background","red");
    $("#content-message").attr('data-div' , getIndex).show();
  });
  $(".delete-div").on("click", function () {
      var getIndex = parseInt($('#content-message').attr('data-div') , 10);
      alert(getIndex);
      $('.content-link').eq(getIndex - 1).remove();
      $('#content-message').hide();
  });
  $(".cancel-div").on("click", function () {
        $('#content-message').hide();
  });
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/000dqyLd/2/)